# How do I set the X,Y position of the cursor in python 3

Tags: python, console-application, python-3.9

I am using python 3.9, and PyCharm as my editor, but run the python files through the regular windows cmd.

So I am wondering is there any way that I can set the cursor position (specify where I want to put text in to CMD console) in python. I have already tried to use:

```
print("\033[6,3;HHello")
```

but it doesn't seem to work, and only prints "<[6,3HHello" directly, instead of printing at the coordinates of 6, 3, Any ideas or examples that I could use?

Comment: You'll need to use a console library like [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), which is included as part of the Python std lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use opencv

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    dim_y = 500 #pixels
    dim_x = int(dim_y*1.618+0.5)
    ground = np.ones((dim_y,dim_x,3))*255
    x_text = 50 #in horizontal axis
    y_text = 50 #in vertical axis
    while True: 
        cv2.putText(ground,'Hello World',(x_text, y_text),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.0, (220, 120, 120),2)
        cv2.imshow('Window Name',ground)
        key = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
        if key == 27: # press ESC to break
            break
    
    cv2.waitKey(0) # press any key to pass
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You need to press ESC to close the new window.

You can pass text at any coordinate whitin dim_x and dim_y.

With modifying the "putText" function, you can print whatever you type in realtime.

More information in this Github Repo [Snake](https://github.com/Hesam-Eskandari/Snake)